# Dictionary comprehension for repeated assignments

Tags: python-2.7, sage

I have a code to construct a dictionary like this.

```
z=1
for r in xrange(m):
        D[z]=r
        z=(z*g)%p
```

How can I convert this into a dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, the `z` value you use as a key into the dictionary is always `g**r % p`. This lets you get rid of the `z` variable and compute your keys directly from `r` (and `g` and `p`):

```
D = {g**r % p: r for r in xrange(m)}
```

Comment: Basically I want to run the loop as fast as possible. Repeated computation of g**r%p takes more time than the loop. Do you know any method?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there's any way to do the z=z*g%p computation in an expression. Perhaps you could write a generator function to do it, then `zip` that generator together with your `xrange` in the comprehension? If performance is more important than readability, I'd just stick with the loop you have.